# How to integrate Ambari REST API for cluster monitoring examples

Tags: rest, monitoring, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I have a use case to integrate and Import Ambari alerts that's getting generated in Ambari Web interface , to the centralized monitoring environment we are using for managing clusters.I am using HDP . Do we have any detailed documentation/Steps/ about how to do this. Here are some example that I want to accomplish

How to make a REST API call to see if HDFS file system if filled and uses is more than 90 % or how to check if if one of service is down like HDFS/HBASE is not working and have raised alarm in Ambari GUI .

Answer (score 5):

Checkout this page for links to the Ambari REST API for alerts:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Alerts

Also checkout slides 4-20 in this SlideShare, particularly slide 13 highlights the Alerts REST API:

http://www.slideshare.net/hortonworks/apache-ambari-whats-new-in-200